# Python MySQLdb: mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064)

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL. Unfortunately, I am getting the error s below:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version fo r the right syntax to use near '1=*,-5000,1)) AND
>   (IF(3=*,5000,3)))at line 1")

volumeMin and volumeMax I put as integer. In actual, it can be float. How can I fix the error?

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxx$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
curs = db.cursor()
name ='G%'
volumeMin = 1
volumeMax = 3
#request args was initially want to retrieve data from external app
#but eventually found that the problem is in MySQL request
"""name = request.args['name']
volumeMin = request.args['volumeMin']
volumeMax = request.args['volumeMax']
"""

query0 = "SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE %s AND "
query2 = "(Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF %s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s)))"

query = query0+query2
input = name,volumeMin,volumeMin,volumeMax,volumeMax
print query
print input
print (query,(input))
curs.execute(query,(input))
a = curs.fetchall()
```

output of print (query,(input))

```
('SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE %s AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF %s=_,-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s=_,5000,%s))) AND MACD LIKE %s ', ('G%', 1, 1
, 3, 3, 'H'))
```

solved

```
query2 = "(Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF (%s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s)))"
```

miss out a bracket

Comment: Can you update your question with output of line `print (query,(input))`?

Comment: @kiran.koduru, updated the print

Comment: So this is what your query translates to `SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE G% AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF 1=_,-5000,1)) AND (IF(3=_,5000,3))) AND MACD LIKE H`. If you paste that in `mysql` you will see there is a problem with the syntax of your query.

Comment: @kiran.koduru, it shows the same `error 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '% AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF 1='_',-5000,1)) AND (IF(3='_',5000,3))) AND' at line 1` .

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE 'G%' AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF 1='_',-5000,1)) AND (IF(3='_',5000,3))) AND MACD LIKE 'H';`, the error observe is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '1='_',-5000,1)) AND (IF(3='_',5000,3))) AND MACD LIKE 'H'' at line 1`. Seems like 'G%' and 'H' for string is correct but for integer and underscore, I really can not figure out.